# Schema design: How do you incorporate "total"?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, schema

I am currently building a scoring table for my items.

Each item has a score so the database (postgres) can sort the item by scores and return them to the user.

Currently, the total score of the product is determined by the following formula:

- Freshness score (calculated by process A)
- Popularity score (calculated by process B)
- Relevance score (calculated by process C)

> Total = 0.5 * freshness + 0.25 * popularity + 0.25 * relevance

Process A, B, C will run over a couple of hours and produce (item_id, score, type) where type can be either "fresh", "popular", or "relevant".

Note that I have to persist these values as they are produced by different processes.

What do I need to do such that I can execute `SELECT * FROM items JOIN scores ON items.id == scores.item_id ORDER BY <total_score ??> DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;`

**EDIT**

An obvious answer is to have another process generate `type = total` for all the items. This works, but it's a pain in the ass because every change in either one of those scores will require total to be updated. In addition, it pretty much can increase my data storage from 25% to 100%. I don't consider this an optimal solution because there is quite a bit of up keeping required to incorporate this.

**UPDATE**

This is my scores table:

```
    Column     |            Type             |                         Modifiers                         | Storage  | Description
---------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+----------+-------------
 created_at    | timestamp without time zone |                                                           | plain    |
 updated_at    | timestamp without time zone |                                                           | plain    |
 id            | integer                     | not null default                             | plain    |
 score         | double precision            | not null                                                  | plain    |
 type          | character varying           | not null                                                  | extended |
```

Comment: You could create a trigger to update the total score whenever one of its components changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another cool way to do this using a virtual column, as described [here](http://momjian.us/main/blogs/pgblog/2013.html#April_1_2013):

First, create a view to aggregate the scores for each item:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_scores_rollup AS
SELECT id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'freshness' THEN score ELSE 0 END) AS freshness,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'popularity' THEN score ELSE 0 END) AS popularity,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'relevance' THEN score ELSE 0 END) AS relevance
FROM scores
GROUP BY id;
```

Next, this function takes the source table/view as the argument.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION total(vw_scores_rollup) RETURNS numeric AS
$BODY$
  SELECT 0.5 * COALESCE($1.freshness, 0) + 0.25 * COALESCE($1.popularity, 0) + 0.25 * COALESCE($1.relevance, 0);
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql;
```

To access:

```
SELECT *, s.total
FROM items i
JOIN vw_scores_rollup s USING (id)
ORDER BY s.total DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

This is a neat trick and provides a straightforward way to access the total.

Comment: See update to question showing that the score table doesn't have these columns (btw I've corrected by answer to accommodate the new info)

Comment: a) take a look at the post I mentioned. `s.total` is a short-hand method of calling total() and passing the row. b) thanks! I hadn't seen the change...will edit

Comment: @mu: Great explanation in the blog. My original answer assumed that freshness, popularity, and relevance were columns in the scores table. If structured that way, you could index `s.total` - I've used that technique for fast access to ranked data.

Comment: Don't forget to do SELECT coalesce(0.5 * $1.freshness, 0) + coalesce(0.25 * $1.popularity, 0) + coalesce(0.25 * $1.relevance, 0)

Comment: @disappearedng: Good catch - thanks! I changed the view so it would return 0 if no records for a given type. Though it's somewhat redundant, I added `COALESCE` to the total function as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Order by the expression for the total score, joining to each score row separately so that all score types can be used in the calculation.

```
SELECT * FROM items
LEFT JOIN scores f ON items.id = f.item_id and type = 'freshness'
LEFT JOIN scores p ON items.id = p.item_id and type = 'popularity'
LEFT JOIN scores r ON items.id = r.item_id and type = 'relevance'
ORDER BY 
    0.5 * COALESCE(f.score, 0) +
    0.25 * COALESCE((p.score, 0) +
    0.25 * COALESCE(r.score) DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

There is no need to store the total.

Note the use of `LEFT JOIN`, which means that items without particular score types will still be returned. I used `COALESCE()` to give a score of zero for any missing score types.

You may think this will cause a performance problem, but I doubt it. Try it and see how it performs before you consider storing the total, which would be for performance reasons only and therefore a case of "optimizing early" - an anti-pattern to be avoided.

Comment: @Bohemian: quick note that you meant "=" instead of "=="...familiar typo when switching languages!

Comment: @marcj damn! that was the first thing i noticed about the query, but i lasily copy-pasted it. Fixed now. thx!

Comment: @Bohemian How can you actually say `ORDER BY 0.5 * freshness...` if the results are from the scores table itself?

Comment: Now that you have posted the schema, it's more clear. Please see edited answer for how you get all score types to be factored in

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

```
SELECT item_id, SUM(S) TOTAL
FROM (
  SELECT item_id, 0.5 * score S
      FROM scores
      WHERE type = 'freshness'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT item_id, 0.25 * score
      FROM scores
      WHERE type IN ('popularity', 'relevance')
) Q1
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC;
```

[[SQL Fiddle]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a18c4/7)

This will give you item IDs and the associated total scores (sorted by from highest to lowest).

You can easily JOIN that with the `items` table if necessary, LIMIT to top 10 etc...

---

Another possibility...

```
SELECT
    item_id,
    SUM (
        CASE type
            WHEN 'freshness' THEN 0.5
            WHEN 'popularity' THEN 0.25
            WHEN 'relevance' THEN 0.25
        END
        * score
    ) TOTAL
FROM scores
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for multiple joins. Just aggregate before joining.

```
select i.*, s.total
from
    items i
    inner join
    (
        select
            id,
                coalesce(sum((type = 'fresh')::integer * score * 0.5), 0)
                + coalesce(sum((type = 'popularity')::integer * score * 0.25), 0)
                + coalesce(sum((type = 'relevance')::integer * score * 0.25), 0)
            total
        from scores
        group by id
    ) s on i.id = s.id
order by s.total desc
limit 10
```